# Load Data using Spark deletes source file from S3

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3

I'm using Spark to [load data](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-dml-load.html) into a hive table through Pyspark, and when I load data from a path in Amazon S3, the original file is getting wiped from the Directory. The file is found, and is populating the table with data. I also tried to add the `Local` clause but that throws an error when looking for the file. When looking through the documentation it doesn't explicitly state that this is the intended behavior.

```
spark.sql("CREATE TABLE src (key INT, value STRING) STORED AS textfile")
spark.sql("LOAD DATA INPATH 's3://bucket/kv1.txt' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE src")
```